# How to extract two groups of tuples into a single variable?

Tags: apache-pig

I need to extract the LOG_COUNT1 and LOG_COUNT2 into a single group of two records of structure: `police_force, date, crime_count`

```
joined_tbl: {group: chararray,LOG_COUNT1: {(police_force: chararray,date: chararray,crime_count: long)},LOG_COUNT2: {(police_force: chararray,date: chararray,crime_count: long)}}
```

Comment: You want to merge `LOG_COUNT1` and `LOG_COUNT2`? Like `{group: chararray,LOG_COUNT: {(police_force: chararray,date: chararray,crime_count: long), (police_force: chararray,date: chararray,crime_count: long)}}`

Comment: yes please, thats exactly it. It feels like I have tried everything, but I have only been learning apache pig for two days @franklinsijo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
F1 = FOREACH joined_tbl GENERATE group, FLATTEN(LOG_COUNT1) ;
F2 = FOREACH joined_tbl GENERATE group, FLATTEN(LOG_COUNT2) ;
U = UNION F1, F2 ;
# merged_tbl = FOREACH (GROUP U BY group) GENERATE group AS group, U.(police_force, date, crime_count) AS LOG_COUNT;
DUMP U;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the last two lines were not needed (and was giving me an error to run) but just union joining does the job

Comment: That loop was added to get the desired bag format. I will update the answer to exclude it. I did not generate any sample data to test it. Can you say what was the error?

Comment: 2020-04-03 19:33:56,863 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 32, column 58>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'group'